# How to make Paging work with Jquery tablesorter

Tags: jquery

i am using Jquery tablesorter .

I want to show initailly 3 records in the table

I tried with the option as shown below

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".testtable").tablesorter({
        widgets: ["filter", "scroller"],
        widgetOptions: {

        }
    }).tablesorterPager({
        container: $(".pager"),
        size: 3
    });
});
```

But why the paging is not working in this case ??

This is my fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/99p3yvv6/8/

Comment: Your JSFiddle appears to work fine once you change tabs... Why do you have multiple `$(document).ready...` calls? Combine them into 1 and see what happens

Comment: please click on the tabs multiple times ..

Comment: Table shows fine? What is your exact problem other than 'not working'. Combine your `$(document).ready` calls into 1, having 2 means one is being overwritten

Comment: even though i comibed into 1 , its having a issue http://jsfiddle.net/99p3yvv6/10/

Comment: What's the problem? You need to be more clear about what you expect it to do and what it is actually doing right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is with the pagers. You need to define seperate pagers for each tables adding

```
<div class="pager"> 
    <img src="http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/addons/pager/icons/first.png" class="first"/> 
    <img src="http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/addons/pager/icons/prev.png" class="prev"/> 
    <span class="pagedisplay"></span> <!-- this can be any element, including an input --> 
    <img src="http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/addons/pager/icons/next.png" class="next"/> 
    <img src="http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/addons/pager/icons/last.png" class="last"/>       
</div>
```

after the tables then your tablesorter code should be like:

```
$(".testtable").each(function(){
     $(this).tablesorter({
       widgets: ["filter", "scroller"],
       widgetOptions: { }
     }).tablesorterPager({
       container: $(this).parent().find(".pager"),
       size: 3
     });
});
```

[UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/99p3yvv6/13/)

Answer (score 2):

The problem isn't the table sorter, it's the loading of the data.

You are loading the data only on click of the tabs, you should add a load of first tab in the `ready` function or such.

**EDIT**

You can use the code from your click handler to fix the issue. [See here](http://jsfiddle.net/jnfsmile/99p3yvv6/14/)

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
  var datatoselect = myjsonresponse1;
  var html = "";
  html += '';
  for (var e = 0; e < datatoselect.length; e++) {
    html += "<tr><td>" + datatoselect[e].name + "</td><td>" + datatoselect[e].date_time + "</td></tr>"
  }

  $(".testtable tbody:visible").html(html);
  $(".testtable").tablesorter({
  ...
```

You would need to comment out this one:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  //$('.ui-tabs-panel').css('display','none');
})
```

since by setting `display:none` you won't find any `tbody:visible`, which is the selector used for loading the data.

Comment: could you please tell me how can i clcik the first tab by default ?? to make this work

Comment: please see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/99p3yvv6/11/ , its still not working...

Comment: I added an example and link to the answer, but for real use you should probably refactor that code out as a separate function.

Comment: Thank you very much for your harwork , but the only issue is the data comes on click of ajax call and its not present by default .

Comment: I don't know how you page/app is set up. You will need to have initial data, either upon page load as a script, or you'll need to make an ajax call on page load and populate the data.